# How do I add Sparks in Google+?

Tags: google-plus

I am trying to add more sparks to my Google+ account but I cannot find where the link to add them has gone. It seems to have been moved and I don't know where.

How can I add more sparks to my Google Plus account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sparks search has been moved to the search box at the top of Google+

When you run your search, your results come back with four filter types:

- Everything
- People
- Google+ posts
- Sparks

Select **Sparks** and then click **Save this search**.

[image: sparks creation in action]

That spark will now be saved to your sidebar for future reference.

Alternatively you can go create/search for a new spark via the following URL:

> https://plus.google.com/s/[searchTerm]/sparks

In this example it would be:

> https://plus.google.com/s/mangoes/sparks

Comment: Ah here it is. Unfortunately when I click "Save this search" it creates a new link with a small magnifier icon in the sidebar that give me all results when I click it. I would like a link that gives me only sparks results, as my old ones. Is it still possible?

Comment: Filtering direct to sparks alone is no longer possible unless you save as a bookmark @dra